# How can I extract two most expensive items from a dictionary using standard library?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to write a function that returns a dictionary with most expensive items. It takes first parameter as no. of items to be extracted, and second parameter for the whole data set. If I add more item for second most expensive, it gets only duplicate value of first item.

```
top = 3
data = [{"name": "bread", "price": 100},
       {"name": "wine", "price": 138},
       {"name": "meat", "price": 15},
       {"name": "water", "price": 1},
       {"name": "fish", "price": 10}]

most_expensive(top: int, data: list) -> list
    mostExpensive = dict(data[0])
        for i in data:
            if i["price"] > mostExpensive["price"]:
                mostExpensive.update(i)
```

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question]( https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow. Best of all, each tutorial will teach you a collection of related techniques, rather than merely solving the immediate problem.

Comment: Guys, thank you for pointing out and it's my bad English that made my question seems like I want this, can you do this for me. That was not my intention, what I really meant is my code is not in the right direction, and I want to ask where it goes wrong. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could sort the `list` of dictionaries by the price reversed and then use slicing notation to return the `top` results.

```
from operator import itemgetter

top = 3
data = [{"name": "bread", "price": 100},
       {"name": "wine", "price": 138},
       {"name": "meat", "price": 15},
       {"name": "water", "price": 1},
       {"name": "fish", "price": 10}]

print(sorted(data, key=itemgetter('price'), reverse=True)[:top])
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'wine', 'price': 138}, 
{'name': 'bread', 'price': 100}, 
{'name': 'meat', 'price': 15}]
```

Comment: I got it with your help. I overlooked sort() built-in function in documentation and your solution gives exactly what I want to get. I modify it as `(sorted(data, key=lambda k:k['price'], reverse=True))[:limit]`

Comment: @Mgph Thanks for the accept! You can use a `lambda` to avoid the `from operator import itemgetter`  statement. Remember `sorted()` returns a copy, while `sort()` modifies in-place without returning anything. If you got any more questions, in the future, I will be glad to answer them.